# Simple Regexp With Odd Return

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get data from a simple regex but it is returning odd values.

I'm using

```
/(.*) kbps \|/siU
```

To parse a page with the following data:

```
<b>Bit Rate:</b>

             320 kbps |
```

I am trying to get the bitrate.  Any suggestions?

Best,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = '<b>Bit Rate:</b>

             320 kbps |';

preg_match('#Bit Rate[^\d]+([\w\s]+\w)#msi', $str, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);

?>

// Output
string(8) "320 kbps"
```

It all depends on how robust the regex must be. For example, the above will look specifically for a stream of word ([A-Za-z0-9_]) following "Bit Rate" and at least one non-numeric character in between (The end of a tag, some spaces etc.) `[\w\s]+\w` ensures that the last character is not a whitespace, but that it can contain whitespaces until the last word character.